# Binding TabItem Header to Textblock in Style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

I'm trying to create a tab control in which the Header on the TabItem is binded in a textbox that is in the controltemplate of the tabcontrol. how can i do this through binding in the style?

Here's my code:

```
<Style x:Key="TabControlTest1" TargetType="TabControl">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!--Area for TabItems-->
                <Border Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    >
                    <TabPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                        x:Name="HeaderPanel" 
                        Background="Transparent" />
                </Border>

                <!--Content of SelectedItems-->
                <Border Grid.Column="1" 
                     BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TabControlContentPresentBorderBrush}"
                     BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"
                     Background="{DynamicResource TabControlContentPresentBackgroundBrush}"
                     >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--///This is Where I want to bind the Header///-->
                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Foreground="AliceBlue"
                            Content="{Binding Header, ElementName=TabItem}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter 
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                            ContentSource="SelectedContent"
                            Margin="5"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Border>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TabItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <!--Grid Defines Height and also hold content header-->
            <Grid>

                <Border Background="{DynamicResource TabItemContentPresentBackgroundBrush}"
                Margin="0,0,0,5">

                    <!--Content of TabItem will be rendered-->
                    <ContentPresenter 
                        x:Name="ContentSite" 
                        Margin="3"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                        ContentSource="Header"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<Label Grid.Row="0"
       Foreground="AliceBlue"
       Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabControl}
       , Path=SelectedItem.Header}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and achieve this either using TemplateBinding or using RelativeSource.
TemplateBinding:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0"
       Foreground="AliceBlue"
       Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
```

RelativeSource:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0"
       Foreground="AliceBlue"
       Content="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}"/>
```

Comment: This is the way I wanted to go. I tried using the Relative Source but it doesn't work for TabItem. If i changed Ancestor Type to Window and Path to Title, it renders correctly. Not sure why it's not showing.

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed. It doesn't work since you're defining it in TabControl template, not in TabItems template. So you're trying to bind from TabControl through FindAncestor(though it's child, not ancestor). You should move code to TabItem template.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't using a control template, but demonstrates binding a textbox to the tab header through a view model.  Note that I'm using MVVM light (ViewModelBase and Set()), but you can replace with your own INotifyPropertyChanged support if necessary.

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Samples:TabBindingViewModel}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyContent}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Header}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TabControl 
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate}" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Header" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</Grid>

public class TabContentToHeaderViewModels : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TabContentToHeaderViewModel> _items;

    public TabContentToHeaderViewModels()
    {
        _items = new ObservableCollection<TabContentToHeaderViewModel>
                     {
                         new TabContentToHeaderViewModel(1),
                         new TabContentToHeaderViewModel(2),
                         new TabContentToHeaderViewModel(3),
                     };
    }

    public IEnumerable<TabContentToHeaderViewModel> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }
}

public class TabContentToHeaderViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public TabContentToHeaderViewModel() : this(0)
    {
    }

    public TabContentToHeaderViewModel(int n)
    {
        Header = "I'm the header: " + n.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        MyContent = "I'm the content: " + n.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    private string _header;
    public string Header
    {
        get { return _header; }
        set { Set(() => Header, ref _header, value); }
    }

    public string MyContent { get; set; }
}
```